# How to Load the pre-trained word embeddings in .npy files

Tags: python, nlp, word-embedding

I'm trying to use the word embeddings pre-trained in [HistWords Project](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/histwords/) by the Stanford NLP team. But when I ran the document **example.py** from the [GitHub website](https://github.com/williamleif/histwords), there was an error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'representations.sequentialembedding'**.
How can I solve this problem?

I've installed the "representations" module, but it doesn't work. The pre-trained word embeddings are of ".npy" format, is there any Python-based method for uploading them?

Comment: `representations.sequentialembedding` are two subfolders of the repository you provided. Beside the given requirements(.txt) no further installation should be necessary. Did you use `git clone` are you running example.py (with python2.7) directly in the directory? For me that works. Can you clarify what you mean with "uploading" the .npy files? Is running the module your question or just loading the npy files?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! According to your comment, I found the document "sequentialembedding.py" in the repository and used git clone to create a copy of the whole. I interpreted codes in "example.py" as firstly uploading the pre-trained word embeddings and then making use of them (Maybe I've got a wrong understanding). And when I ran the first code line with anaconda-spyder, an error occurred. So I posted a question about "uploading". But my target is to successfully run example.py and use these pre-trained embeddings to track diachronic changes of several words at semantic level.

Comment: I just found that I ran this document with python3.9. And I'll look up how to set the environment to python2.7. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set it up you can do the following in your shell:

```
cd <path you want to store your project>
git clone https://github.com/williamleif/histwords.git
cd histwords

# ----- Set up Python2.7 -----
## Python2.7 via conda is quite easy
conda create -y -n <env_name> python=2.7
conda activate <env_name>

## Else install/locate a python 2 version
### Check python -V (maybe its python2.7)
### Maybe you have python2 or python2.7 executables
### On linux you could look for ls /usr/bin/python* 
python2 -m venv <env_name>
source <env_name>/bin/activate # if you use linux
bin/Scripts/activate # on Windows

# ---- Now with Python2.7 ----
pip install -r requirements.txt

# ---- Download & Move your embedding from https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/histwords/
# to embeddings/<category> subfolders

python examples.py
# Outputs the similarities
```